# Problems while Cropping ROI with mouse using Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-3.6, opencv3.0

Following are the two problems that I am facing:

1. The cropping works only if mouse is drag from top left corner to the bottom right.
2. Number of rectangles are drawn like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVEz3.png), though the cropping works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4WLr.png).

Here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cropping = False
x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0

def mouse_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping,refPoint

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
        cropping = True
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if cropping == True:
            x_end, y_end = x, y
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        x_end, y_end = x, y
        cropping = False 
        refPoint = [(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)]

image = cv2.imread('orig.jpg')
oriImage = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", mouse_crop)

while True:
    if not cropping:
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
    elif cropping:
         cv2.rectangle(image, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", image) 
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == (27):
        image = oriImage.copy()
    elif key == (13):
        break
if len(refPoint) == 2:
    roi = oriImage[refPoint[0][1]:refPoint[1][1], refPoint[0][0]:refPoint[1][0]]
    cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: maybe something like "if x/y_start < x/_end do it as you do, otherwise: refPoint = [(x_end, y_end), (x_start, y_start)] ?

Comment: about the drawing: keep the original image and draw/render only a copy (new copy each iteration) so no old rectangles are still on that image.

Comment: I cant understand the first comment @Micka said but second one solve the problem of repeated triangle but now  when i release mouse button the drawn rectangle vanishes, though the cropping is working.

Comment: the first idea was incomplete, sorry. Use `cv2.boundingRect(points)` before drawing the rect or saving the rect to refPoint. `points` here is the unordered list of start and end point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem1 solution:

```
if len(refPoint) == 2:
    print(refPoint[0][0],refPoint[0][1],refPoint[1][0],refPoint[1][1])
    x_s = refPoint[0][0]
    y_s = refPoint[0][1]
    x_e = refPoint[1][0]
    y_e = refPoint[1][1]
    x_big, x_small = ((x_s, x_e) if x_s>x_e else (x_e, x_s))
    y_big, y_small = ((y_s, y_e) if y_s>y_e else (y_e, y_s))
    roi = oriImage[y_small:y_big, x_small:x_big]          
    cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Problem2 Solution: Just add this line: image = oriImage.copy() like this:

```
while True:
if not cropping:
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
elif cropping:
    image = oriImage.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("image", image) 
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == (27):
    image = oriImage.copy()
elif key == (13):
    break
```